# How to extract first letter of every nth word in a sentence?

Tags: python, function, split, extract

I was trying to extract the first letter of every 5th word and after doing a bit of research I was able to figure out how to obtain every 5th word. But, how do I know extract the first letters of every 5th word and put them together to make a word out of them. This is my progress so far:

```
def extract(text):
    for word in text.split()[::5]:
        print(word)

extract("I like to jump on trees when I am bored")
```

Comment: you can just take the 0th element of the string like word[0]

Comment: BTW, there have been dozens of similar questions, to the task you are stuck on. google `python split extract first letter of every word in string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment pointed out, split it and then just access the first character:

```py
def extract(text):
    for word in text.split(" "):
        print(word[0])
```

`text.split(" ")` returns an array and we are looping through that array. `word` is the current entry (`string`) in that array. Now, in python you can access the first character of a string in typical array notation. Therefore, `word[0]` returns the first character of that word, `word[-1]` would return the last character of that word.

Comment: I might be a but stupid but when you do word[0] why do you get the first letter of every word and not for example just the first word as a whole or even only the first letter of the first word.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Upvote questions or answers that helped you out. I have edited my answer to include more details.  If you are just getting started with python please refer to this link for further information: https://pythonbasics.org/strings/

Comment: @AmalJaimon it's because word is an element shifting through the list created by the .split and not the whole sentence variable (text)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how did you solve the first part and can not solve the second one,
but anyway, strings in python are simply a list of characters, so if you want to access the 1st character you get the 0th index. so applying that to your example, as the comment mentioned you type (word[0]),

so you can print the word[0] or maybe collect the 1st characters in a list to do any further operations (I do believe that what you want to do, not just printing them!)

```
def extract(text):
    mychars=[]
    for word in text.split()[::5]:
        mychars.append(word[0])
    print(mychars)

extract("I like to jump on trees when I am bored")
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code might help you out. Just an example idea based on what you said.

```
 #
 # str Text   : A string of words, such as a sentence.
 # int split  : Split the string every nth word 
 # int maxLen : Max number of chars extracted from beginning of each word
 #

 def extract(text,split,maxLen):
     newWord = ""
     # Every nth word
     for word in text.split()[::split]:
         if len(word) < maxLen:
              newWord += word[0:] #Entire word (if maxLength is small)
         else:
              newWord += word[:maxLen] #Beginning of word until nth letter
     return (None if newWord=="" else newWord) 

 text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

 result = extract(text, split=5, maxLen=2) #Use split=5, maxLen=1 to do what you said specifically

 if (result):
      print (result) #Expected output: "Thov"
```